# How to use a computer as a bluetooth headset?

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth, a2dp

I have very little bluetooth expertize. All I want to do is to occasionally be able to use my computer's speakers and microphone for phone conversations. I don't want to use a bluetooth headset.

All tutorials I can find on the Net are either dated for Ubuntu 12.04 at the very latest, or describe the process of connecting to the bluetooth headset.

I have Ubuntu 14.04 64bit Asus N56VZ notebook with built-in bluetooth device, that works well under Ubuntu.

My phone is Nokia 6310i, and is compatible with bluetooth headsets. I know how to connect this phone to the dedicated headset. I just don't know how to connect it to my notebook for the same purpose.

---

When I initiate connection from my mobile to the notebook, or initiate connection from my notebook to the mobile or just turn off the bluetooth and the mobile altogether I've got the same, list sources (obtained via `pactl list sinks` and `pactl list sources` and filtering out all other fields):

```
Sink #0
    Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
Source #0
    Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor
Source #1
    Name: alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
```

I guess one don't "just connect" to the mobile without some extra preparation. The connection connects, and after a second disconnects. I guess I need to make the computer to advertise itself as a headset, otherwise the phone might think it is something different and it doesn't want to deal with it.

This is my `/etc/bluetooth/audio.conf`. By manipulating its contents I never saw any effect (and of course I did reboot after each change), so maybe this file is depreciated. Or the effects are too subtle for me to see.

```
[General]
AutoConnect=true
Enable = Sink,Source,Gateway

[Headset]
HFP=true
MaxConnected=1
FastConnectable=false

[A2DP]
SBCSources=1
MPEG12Sources=0
```

Comment: Have you tried the tutorials for 12.04? Chances are that they still hold for 14.04. If they use PulseAudio, then it will probably work.

Comment: @hal7df I tried one, and it just didn't work. I assumed that these 2 years is just too much for the tutorial to work. As I said, I have very limited knowledge of bluetooth technology and it is very hard for me to tell what to expect and how to debug. In ideal world I'd assume that there is an application like `blueman-services` that can run an audio bluetooth server, like it is supposed to do. But that doesn't and I really don't know if that is a feasible way. There are at least 3 competing programs for bluetooth: bluez, blueman and built-in network manager, that may conflict with each other.

Comment: Maybe, for start, I should ask how to setup *any* bluetooth client-server connection that works between 2 Ubuntu notebooks. That may give me at least some baseline, from where I can expand my knowledge.

Comment: Okay. The way that I would think to do it is by creating PulseAudio loopback modules between the phone and the laptop's audio. What is the output of `pactl list sources` and `pactl list sinks` with your phone connected? (If you want to trim the output, all you really need is the `Name` field)

Comment: @hal7df Thank you for answer. I've updated the question with extra info that I think might be relevant.

Comment: That's interesting... Does either your phone or your netbook indicate that its Bluetooth is connected?

Comment: @hal7df They connect for about 1 sec, and then disconnect.

Comment: Hmm... sounds like your Bluetooth adapter is acting a little funky... not really sure what to do about it. Can it connect to other Bluetooth devices without a problem?

Comment: Well, I can connect to the bluetooth headset. @hal7df, I have two more Ubuntu computers with bluetooth. I will try to make a connection between them with bluetooth and see what happens.